# Migrate users from one domain to another domain by using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, integrate-remedy-sp2013

I would like to migrate users from one domain to another domain.Can you please help here power shell scripting for this?

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Claims, the cmdlet looks like this:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity 'i:0#.w|oldDomain\jdoe' -Web http://webUrl #A site collection where 'jdoe' exists
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias 'i:0#.w|newDomain\jdoe' -IgnoreSid
```

[Move-SPUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps)